# How to retrieve view controller that currently controls status bar appearance?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to retrieve, from anywhere in an app, the view controller that is currently controlling the status bar appearance?

Answer (score 1):

Dont think you can retrieve in a controller that way, but you can change the style of the status bar.

1) set the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES in the plist

2) in viewDidLoad do a [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

3) add the following method:

```
 -(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
 }
```

Comment: My problem is that I have a fullscreen modal being presented from a popover, and the control of the status bar appearance is not transferred to the modal, so following those steps does nothing. The only solution I've found is to dig through the `presentingViewController`s and change the navigation bar style of the navigation controller in charge of the status bar appearance.

Comment: I didnt know modal controller has such limitation. I would guess since its just another viewController, the above should work.. But navigationController might also work since modal view is still under that navigation controller.